# Use robots.txt file to block everything except images

Tags: cdn, robots.txt

I only serve images to my CDN.

I have a robots.txt file set up in my CDN domain which is separate from the one set up in my 'normal' www domain.

I want to format the CDN robots.txt file in my CDN domain so that it blocks the indexing of everything except images (regardless of their location)?

The reason for all this is that I want to avoid duplicate content.

Is this correct?

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: / 
Allow: /*.jpg$
Allow: /*.jpeg$
Allow: /*.gif$
Allow: /*.png$
```

Comment: i'll make an edit to my answer with additional info - hope that is what you are looking for ;)

Comment: I'll make another edit to my post - give me a sec..

Comment: If my post satisfies your questions you are welcome to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have all images in certain folders, you could use:

For google-bot only:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /some-images-folder/
```

For all user-agents:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /some-images-folder/
```

> Additionally, Google has introduced increased flexibility to the
>   robots.txt file standard through the use asterisks. Disallow patterns
>   may include "*" to match any sequence of characters, and patterns may
>   end in "$" to indicate the end of a name.

To allow a specific file type (for example.gif images) you can use following robots.txt entry:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /*.gif$
```

> Info 1: By default (in case you don't have a robots.txt), all content is crawled.
>
> Info 2: The Allow statement should come before the Disallow statement, no matter how specific your statements are..

Here's a wiki link to the [robot's exclusion standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive) for a more detailed description.

According to that, your example should look like:

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /*.jpg$
Allow: /*.jpeg$
Allow: /*.gif$
Allow: /*.png$
Disallow: /
```

**NOTE:** As nev pointed out in his comment it's also important to watch out for query strings at the end of extensions, like `image.jpg?x12345`, so also include

```
  Allow: /*.jpg?*$
```

Comment: So my example would work then ?  I was worried that that the precedence was right (the "allows" after the "disallow")

Comment: So, as per your Edit2, should I reverse the order of the "allows" and "disallows" ?

Comment: @nev Yes - I provided the corrected example at the bottom of my answer and a link to the exclusion standard on wikipedia ;)

Comment: Using the Google sitemap tester, the order of the allows and disallows doesn't seem to make any difference, but your recommendation nevertheless seems better.  I suppose images that have query strings would be tripped up, but my sitemap doesn't include them so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @nev I experienced the same - for most agents the order doesn't seem to matter, but I'd rather stick to the official convention/standard as described in the link ;)

Comment: Just a note here that might be helpful - I had to watch out for query strings at the end of extensions, like image.jpg?x12345, so also include `Allow: /*.jpg?*$`

Comment: @nev : thank you for the info - I'll add your note to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! Disallow is right! Allow is right too!
And just as a tip specify a sitemap too! :)